# Не могу создать таблицу опять (

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

```sql
CREATE TABLE Investments
(
    IDInvestment INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    AccountNumber INT NOT NULL,
    Type VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL,
    InvSum INT,
    Per_Cents FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Currency VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL, 
    OpenningDate DATETIME,
    PasportSN CHAR (11) NOT NULL,
            UNIQUE (AccountNumber),
    FOREIGN KEY (PasportSN) REFERENCES Investors(PasportSN)
)
```

> ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: Автоинкремент сделал - так сделай это поле и первичным индексом. Ведь явно же пишут - "it must be defined as a key".

Comment: немного не понимаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавте Primary Key

```
CREATE TABLE Investments
(
    IDInvestment INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    AccountNumber INT NOT NULL,
    Type VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL,
    InvSum INT,
    Per_Cents FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Currency VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL, 
    OpenningDate DATETIME,
    PasportSN CHAR (11) NOT NULL,
            UNIQUE (AccountNumber),
    FOREIGN KEY (PasportSN) REFERENCES Investors(PasportSN)
)
```

Comment: Советую детальнее ознакомится с синтаксисом и возможностями SQL, конкретно о первичном ключе можно ознакомится например [здесь](https://andreyex.ru/bazy-dannyx/uchebnoe-posobie-po-sql/sql-primary-key-pervichnyj-klyuch/)